# WPF Data Listing

Tags: wpf, list, datagrid

i am the new guy in WPF. I want to display employer list effectively. I don't want to use standard `DataGrid`. It looks like Repeater in asp.net. It should include two record in one row and i can customize view e.g. left side put an image right side some information some check boxes like that (not runtime). What is your suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a ListBox. Bind the ItemsSource property to your collection, and customize the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="{EmployersList}"><!-- if you are using MVVM, bind the items here -->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
                 </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And in code behind:

```
employers = // get from database or web service
EmployerList.ItemsSource = employers;
```